# Is it possible for Ant to lists failed tests at the end of a build?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant

The following snippet, from another thread, works to print a message and fail after all unit tests have been run :

```
<fail if="junit.failed" message="Oh no ! There were some failed unit tests :( "/>
```

However --- I don't see a how can I also record and print the NAMES of the failed tests in junit/ant, after they have all run.  Any thoughts on this  ?

I believe others would find such function extremely important, so I'm assuming a simple solution exists : its quite tedious to look through hundreds of failed tests for the offenders.

Comment: Don't your IDE allow you to run all tests in your code, or part of them? IDEA, for example, allows to see which tests failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. Try using the [junitreport](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) task.

e.g.

Try this attribute on your junit task:

`printsummary="yes"` on junit task

Change your formatter to:

```
<formatter type="xml" />
```

and then create the reports with a target that calls this:

```
<junitreport>
<fileset dir="${testReport.dir}/tmp">
      <include name="*.xml" />
</fileset>
<report format="frames" styledir="${testReportXslt.dir}" todir="${finalReport.dir}/html" />
</junitreport>
```

**For output :**

```
    <concat>
        <fileset dir="${finalReport.dir}/html" includes="*.html"/>
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern='some pattern' />
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </concat>
```

Comment: can this print to the console ?

Comment: @jayunit100 In order to print to output you need to read the final file and extract whatever information you want. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ! But this is quite odd : I'm getting xsl errors.  Isn't all this HTML generation a little bit of overkill for just a simple grep ?

Comment: @jayunit100 Well not really. Standard junit output is .xml. Best way I know of extracting data out of .xml is .xsl.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks. Any thoughts on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234356/why-does-junit-complain-about-missing-xsl-files ?

Comment: ooops ha funny you saw it before I even told you.

Comment: I notice each XML file has a "<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" hostname="doolittle-5.local" name="MyTestName" tests="1" time="0.08" timestamp="2011-11-22T22:16:38">" at the header.  why not just grep that directly ?

Comment: @jayunit100 You can use grep, or any other regex tool if what you want is as simple at that. Don't try to extract nested elements though with the aforementioned tools.

Comment: Thanks again --- so is there a way to simply tell junitreport NOT to use any XSL ?  that way i reduce the dependencies in my app.

Comment: Well if you don't specify that attribute it will default to the embedded stylesheets, which SHOULD exist anywyay :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that many of you have no desire to build a custom formatter or whatever. I don't either. I discovered that, with the following configuration, test successes are printed to stdout while failures are printed to stderr:

```
  <target name="test"
          depends="compile-tests"
          description="runs the unit tests">
    <junit failureproperty="hasFailingTests"
           printsummary="on"
           showoutput="true">
      <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
      <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
          <include name="**/*Test.java" />
          <exclude name="**/Abstract*Test.java" />
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
      <classpath refid="tests.classpath"></classpath>
    </junit>
    <fail if="hasFailingTests" />
  </target>
```

That means that running the following command:

```
ant test > /dev/null
```

will only show stderr with the test failures to the console, making it much easier to see what actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally have a complete answer to this question : Thanks to FailedDev's insights .

First, Make sure you ${reports.dir} variable, specifying the directory for the reports :

```
    <property name="reports.dir" value="reports" />
```

Then , when we begin coding the test instructions junit  :

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
```

Then, make necessary directories for the reports :

```
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}/tmp" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}/style" />
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}/final" />
```

Since we have a report scanner, we can set haltonfailure to no, and fail after (scroll down).

```
    <junit printsummary="yes" failureproperty="junit.failed" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes" forkmode="once">
        <jvmarg value="-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" />
        <classpath refid="common.classpath" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${reports.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                <include name="**/Test*.java" />
                <exclude name="**/AllTests.java" />
                <exclude name="**/*.properties" />
                <exclude name="**/*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
```

Now, here is where the advice of other questions comes in : run the junit report.

```
    <!-- Capture all failures, simple debugging statements. -->
    <junitreport>
        <fileset dir="${reports.dir}/tmp">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${reports.dir}/final" />
    </junitreport>
```

And finally, we can grep the xml files, directly, for errors :

```
    <!-- This could be its own task, i.e., a java class which directly processed junit test data. -->
    <echo message="Now checking xml test results for errors"    />
        <exec executable="grep" error="/dev/null">
            <arg value="-r" />
            <arg value="-m" />
            <arg value="1" />
            <arg value="-rl" />
            <arg value="errors=\&quot;[1-9]\&quot;" /> 
            <arg value="${reports.dir}" />
        </exec>
```

Now, since we are'nt failing early (rather we are running the whole build, so we can see which tests failed , if any) we still have to notify the builder that we have failed... This is done via the fail-if syntax :

```
    <fail if="junit.failed" message="FAILING - unit tests failed." />
    <!-- Now, we check if there were failures, and output the results --> 
</target>
```

Removing my comments, this code-block should work perfectly if you paste it into your build.

Comment: Just to note: This is all well and good if your option is running the build from your command-line (or, I suppose, your IDE.)  However, I also recommend that you look into a Continuous Integration server like Jenkins.  It will compile and run your entire build for you, and through various plugins it can give you pretty graphs and reports on lots of metrics, including passing/failing unit tests.

Comment: Yes : We use jenkins ...   i will see if there is a way to visualize this.