# Why does junit complain about missing xsl files ?

Tags: java, xslt, ant, junit

Im getting a complaint in my Ant build which refers to a missing junit file :

/reports/style/junit-frames.xsl

This error creeped up after I added the  tag to my ant tasks, as a method for printing the failures of unit tests out .

Answer (score 4):

JUnit frames expects XSL stylesheets to format the reports correctly. These are `junit-frames.xsl` and `junit-noframes.xsl`. You'll need to create these files, or copy them from somewhere. I guess you've defined a styledir which doesn't exist or something?

See [JUnitReport task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html), parameters section.

There are example files in `<ant installation directory>/etc`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response.  As FaileDev has noted, I'm actually trying to extract failed test text -- and using the junitreport to do this.  Not sure what the next step is.  I could probably just write my own junit task to extract the failed text directly from the xml, without any styling....  Unless there are some default xsl templates out there.

Comment: @jayunit100 It's easier to just use .xsl. It will take like 5 lines. Just. I bet it's as simple as //failures or something :)

Comment: There are actually example files in <your ant directory>/etc

Answer (score 2):

Because this file probably does not exist and you will have to write it.

I guess you are referring to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231952/is-it-possible-for-ant-to-lists-failed-tests-at-the-end-of-a-build/8232053#8232053)?

Comment: hello again !  hmmm --- found a junit-frames.xsl file online , but it didn't do the trick.  Is there a template out there that will fit my simple needs of getting the failures ?  Or will i need to write my own ?

Comment: You can just write your own. It's not SO hard.. If you post a sample output I can help :)